# Unable to connect to cpanel's phpmyadmin database with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm starting to experiment and explore node.js for a project which involves using tables. So far i've created a MySQL user and database within cpanel and have granted the user full access to the database. I've read the documentation for the npm mysql , but am unable to establish a connection, have tried adding socket path but still does not work, any help would be appreciated.

Node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con= mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : 'localhost',
        port     :  3306,
        user     : '*******',
        password : '*******',
        database : '*******',
});

con.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, results) {
  if(err){
    console.log('Query error: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

Error Message

```
Query error:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Pharmabot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (E:\Pharmabot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (E:\Pharmabot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (E:\Pharmabot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:454:10)
    at Connection.query (E:\Pharmabot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:196:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Pharmabot\database\dbconnect.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some great packages, you must try theme first. there are some packages that support all db server language like sql, mysql2, mongodb, postgres etc.